# Plot a function with ggplot, equivalent of curve()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Is there an equivalent method for plotting functions using `ggplot` to the `curve()` command employed in base graphics? I guess that the alternative would be to just create a vector of values of the function and plot a connected line, but I was hoping for something a bit more simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can add a curve using the `stat_function`:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 10)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun=sin)
```

If your curve function is more complicated, then use a lambda function. For example,

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 10)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=function(x) sin(x) + log(x))
```

you can find other examples at
http://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/draw-function-without-data-in-ggplot2/

---

In earlier versions, you could use `qplot`, as below, but this is now deprecated.

```
qplot(c(0,2), fun=sin, stat="function", geom="line")
```

Comment: For `qplot(c(0,2), fun=sin, stat="function", geom="line")`, `stat` is deprecated now in 2016 and `fun` is no longer an acceptable parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The `data.frame` example above works well, and it makes grid lines.  The `qplot` example doesn't work in ggplot2 2.2.0 for the reasons given.

You can also use the "curve" function in ggplot2 2.2.0, but it does not automatically make grid lines or background color.  For example:

```
curve(cos(x), from= 0, to= pi/2).
```

The "ggplot(data.frame(...  )   method gives the full impressive range of ggplot2's formatting options.  I like it.

Comment: `curve` is a base function, not a ggplot2 function. The reason it doesn't make grid lines or background color like `ggplot2` is because it's not `ggplot2`.