# Plotting two lines in the same graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I know how to plot with R's default plotting function. How do I do the same thing as the following R-code in ggplot2?

```
double <- function(x){
  return(x^2)
}
triple <- function(x){
  return(x^3)
}

xs <- seq(-3,3,0.01)
dou  <- double(xs)
tri <- triple(xs)

plot(rep(xs, 2), c(dou, tri), typ="n")
lines(xs, dou, col="red")
lines(xs, tri, col="green")
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177846/equivalent-of-curve-for-ggplot and http://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/draw-function-without-data-in-ggplot2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to apply the functions before plotting when using `ggplot2`. You can tell `ggplot2` to use your functions.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(as.data.frame(xs), aes(xs)) +
  stat_function(fun = double, colour = "red") + 
  stat_function(fun = triple, colour = "green")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat_function`, but since you don't use `curve` in the base plot, I think your are looking for a simple scatter plot with `geom_line`.

1. put your data in a data.frame : `ggplot2` works with data.frame as data source.
2. reshape the data in the long format : aes works in the long format , generally you plot x versus y according to a third variable z.

For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(xs=xs,dou=dou,tri=tri)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melt(dat,id.vars='xs'),
       aes(xs,value,color=variable))+
  geom_line()
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Using basic plots you can simplify your plots using `curve`:

```
curve(x^3,-3,3,col='green',n=600)
curve(x^2,-3,3,col='red',n=600,add=TRUE)
```

[image]